# Powershell send email to recipients in Excel spreadsheet

Tags: powershell, email

I have a spreadsheet located at C:\scripts\test.csv containing a list of user email addresses.

I'm trying to send the below email to each of these users, but it's only sending to one of the users. How can I send it to all users?

```
$recipients = get-content C:\scripts\test.csv

$smtpServer = "mail.server.com"
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$msg.From = "FromUser@email.com"
$msg.To.Add($recipients)
$msg.subject = "Requiring Updates"
$msg.IsBodyHTML = $true
$body = @'
<html> 
  <body> 
    <font face="calibri">Hello, please read this test email.</font>
  </body> 
</html> 
'@ 

$msg.body = $body
$smtp.Send($msg)
```

Answer (score 3):

So you have to iterate them one by one in a *foreach* loop.

Change your existing code to this:

```
$recipients = get-content C:\scripts\test.csv


foreach($rcpt in $recipients)
{
$smtpServer = "mail.server.com"
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$msg.From = "FromUser@email.com"
$msg.To.Add($rcpt)
$msg.subject = "Requiring Updates"
$msg.IsBodyHTML = $true
$body = @'
<html> 
  <body> 
    <font face="calibri">Hello, please read this test email.</font>
  </body> 
</html> 
'@ 

$msg.body = $body
$smtp.Send($msg)

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Cool thanks. Each user received the email. What would I need to do in order to send just one email, containing all users?

Comment: Same.keep the send option outside the loop. It will send only once after adding all the recipients in the to list.

Comment: @Bondo: Accept the answer if it helps you, that will be appreciable.

Comment: It looks like when I move    $smtp.Send($msg) outside of the loop it only sends the email to the last email address listed.

Comment: no you have to change the logic a little bit. You have to add all the recipients to the (To) part one my one. and then we have to use send. So all the recipients will get added in one single variable and then we can trigger. Else give me sometime. Once I will be free,i will make that.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the new answer since your requirement changed now.

Put the emailIds directly in the csv file one by one without quotes since I am already appending that. Now this will send one email to all the recipients reading from the file.

```
$recipients = get-content C:\scripts\test.csv

Remove-Variable rcpt -ErrorAction Ignore

Remove-Variable result -ErrorAction Ignore

Remove-Variable final_result -ErrorAction Ignore
foreach($rcpt in $recipients)
{

$result += "'$rcpt'" + ","
$final_result=$result.Trim(',')

$smtpServer = "mail.server.com"
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$msg.From = "FromUser@email.com"
$msg.To.Add($final_result)
$msg.subject = "Requiring Updates"
$msg.IsBodyHTML = $true
$body = @'
<html> 
  <body> 
    <font face="calibri">Hello, please read this test email.</font>
  </body> 
</html> 
'@ 

$msg.body = $body


}
$smtp.Send($msg)
```